# Por que no segundo exemplo (diferentemente do primeiro) o resultado sai concatenado e nao somado?

Tags: java

exemplo 1

```
final double BEGIN = 10.20, KM = 1.30, BAG = 2;
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
double clientKm, clientBags;

System.out.println("How many km?:");
clientKm = s.nextDouble();

System.out.println("How many bags?:");
clientBags = s.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Your bill is: " + (BEGIN + (clientKm * KM) + (clientBags * BAG)) + " shekels.");
```

exemplo 2:

```
int floorCome, floorCall, floorGo;
final int FLOORTIME = 3, STOPTIME = 5;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Which floor is the elevator now? ");
floorCome = s.nextInt();

System.out.println("From which floor is the person calling? ");
floorCall = s.nextInt();

System.out.println("To which floor you like to go? ");
floorGo = s.nextInt();

System.out.print("Will take " + STOPTIME + FLOORTIME * (floorCome - floorCall) + FLOORTIME * (floorCall - floorGo) + " seconds.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No primeiro exemplo você usa as "(" e ")" para separar os tipos, se você fazer assim no segundo exemplo, irá funcionar.

```
System.out.print("Will take " + (STOPTIME + FLOORTIME * (floorCome - floorCall) + FLOORTIME * (floorCall - floorGo)) + " seconds.");
```

Answer (score 6):

O java, quando encontra uma expressão do tipo `"String" + tipo primitivo`, usa o método `toString()` do tipo primitivo para obter a *string* que o representa para depois a concatenar com a string anterior, resultando uma nova *string*.

No primeiro caso a concatenação só é feita após a soma porque a existência dos parêntesis provoca que seja primeiro calculado o que está dentro deles e só depois seja efectuada a concatenação.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que tenha sido uma desatenção sua, pois, no primeiro exemplo está concatenando a frase com as variáveis corretamente utilizando os parênteses e fazendo com que o programa faça o cálculo de forma correta, já no segundo exemplo você deixou de colocar um parênteses para separar  expressão matemática da frase, fazendo com que as variáveis possivelmente se concatenem ao invés de ocorrer a solução da expressão matemática. Repare a diferença

```
System.out.println("Your bill is: " + (BEGIN + (clientKm * KM) + (clientBags * BAG)) + " shekels.");

System.out.print("Will take " + STOPTIME + FLOORTIME * (floorCome - floorCall) + FLOORTIME * (floorCall - floorGo) + " seconds.");
```

Portanto troque a segunda linha acima por esta linha abaixo, e reparei que faltou o `ln` no seu `Sytem.out.print`

```
System.out.println("Will take " + (STOPTIME + FLOORTIME * (floorCome - floorCall) + FLOORTIME * (floorCall - floorGo)) + " seconds.");
```